# Copying a Directory when Building Sencha Touch

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch-2

I am building an application in Sencha Touch and PHP. Both parts are being developed on my PC in the same directory. Thus the structure looks something like this:

```
AppDir
  - .sencha
  - app
  - build
  - packages
  - php
  - resources
  - touch
```

Most of what is above is standard to all of the examples I could find online. However, I also have that 'php' subdirectory, which houses an AJAX API that my application uses.

When I build the application, the PHP directory can no longer be found as it is here:

```
http://localhost/AppDir/php/
```

While the application is here:

```
http://localhost/AppDir/build/production/AppDir/
```

I can't figure out a way to force the build process to copy the PHP directory into the output directory (or perhaps alternatively to inform the built application to search several directories higher for the PHP API). I've thought about making it a resource, which would work but seems counter-intuitive.

Can anyone give me any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The build process used by Sencha CMD uses ANT, so you could add in some ANT tasks into the build.xml file to copy this folder, this [link](http://docs.sencha.com/cmd/5.x/advanced_cmd/cmd_build.html) gives a brief introduction to the build process.

The answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22385911/sencha-cmd-build-include-client-specific-files) should give you the information required to add those additional tasks in the build script.

I'm not completely sure that copying this folder to the build/ folder is the right approach though. All of the generated code in the build folder is your compiled / minified front-end application. This is seperate from your backend API service and your build/deployment scripts should probably reflect this.

When you make changes to the front end you would need to build again, but for the backend PHP code, you dont need to do that. In theory, you could deploy your finished code for front end and backend seperately even if they are deployed to the same destination, then only update and deploy the one you have modified as you update them.

Comment: You're point about not deploying them together is valid, but it leaves me with a similar conundrum. How can I point my AJAX requests to the right URL when the URL will vary between development and final deployment? (My original idea of copying was meant to address this by making it the same relative path in both development and build.) I know I can hard-code the URL in a shared object, of course. But is there a better way? Perhaps a file that is modifiable even after the whole thing has been minified?

Comment: It all depends on how you want your production environment really, when you are deploying this you only need the contents of your build/appdir directory. You could place these files in the root of your live hosting account and also put your PHP folder in the same place. So the path to your api would be /php - the same as your dev environment. You could also run your api separately on a sub domain like api.example.com (can cause cross domain issues). You could create deployment scripts to get both of these folders and upload to the same place if needed.